# Lidando com objetos aninhados (nesting) utilizando um ORM

Tags: php, design-pattern, orm, iterator

Vamos supor que em um sistema para uma empresa de ônibus eu tenho entidades: Linha, carro e viagens.
Cada uma, tem três classes:

**A própria entidade,**

```
class Linha extends Model
{
   protected $id;
   // outras propriedades.

   public function getId() {
       return $this->id;
   }
   // outros métodos.
```

**Sua coleção,**

```
class LinhaCollection extends ArrayObject {}
```

**E seu mapeador.**

```
class LinhaMapper extends Mapper
{
    public function findAll() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `linhas`";
        return $this->fetchCollection($sql); // Retorna uma coleção de objetos do tipo Linha.
}
```

---

Então listar todas as linhas é bem simples:

```
$lm = new LinhaMapper;
$linhas = $lm->findAll();

foreach ($linhas as $linha) {
    echo $linha->getNome();
}

/*
 * Linha 123
 * Linha 456
 * Linha 159
 */
```

Quero listar na minha View todas as linhas, carros e viagens da seguinte forma (tipo árvore):

- Linha 123

  - Carro 001

    - Viagem 1
    - Viagem 2
  - Carro 002

    - Viagem 1
    - Viagem 2
- Linha 456...

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

*Desculpem se a explicação foi longa, sou iniciante e não sei se minha solução é muito óbvia.

Os códigos foram simplificados para encurtar a pergunta*

Comment: Oi Lucas, você ainda precisa de ajuda neste assunto?

Comment: Olá Fernando, preciso sim. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK você tem as três entidades independentes, isoladas entre si. Para montar esta árvore você precisa de mais uma ou duas entidades no seu banco de dados, sugestões de acordo com o meu ponto de vista:

1) Relacionar Linhas e Carros. Se um mesmo Carro pode estar em mais de uma Linha será um relacionamento N:N, por exemplo, uma tabela `Linha_Carro`.

2) Na entidade Viagem você deve ter o ID do Carro, para saber *qual carro fez cada viagem*, partindo do princípio que cada viagem só é feita uma vez, e por um único Carro.

Até aqui estamos falando apenas sobre a modelagem do banco de dados.

Na implementação OO da classe Linha você deve criar um atributo que será um array contendo objetos **Carro**, exemplo:

```
class Linha extends Model
{
   protected $id;

   /*
    * @var Carro[] Coleção dos carros vinculados à Linha.
    */
   protected $carros = array();
   // outras propriedades.

   public function getId() {
       return $this->id;
   }
   // outros métodos.
```

No seu Mapper, ao carregar um objeto Linha do banco de dados, após popular os atributos simples você deve popular o atributo `$carros` da coleção, executando um SELECT na tabela **Linha_Carro**.